# Knock Knock Server

Tags: java, sockets, client, port

According to this website, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html
it says this :

Server: "Knock knock!"

Client: "Who's there?"

Server: "Dexter."

Client: "Dexter who?"

Server: "Dexter halls with boughs of holly."

Client: "Groan."

I thought that if the server is listening on a port that it is waiting for a knock, so the client would be knocking and the server would be saying who's there. I've checked other websites as well and have seen the same client/server responses.

Can someone please explain why this is not the case?

Comment: Shouldn't the Client start with knock-knock? I think the protocol is backwards ;-)

Comment: @Joachim I think that was the point of the question. I agree the example seems backwards and so is confusing.

Comment: Well, it seems I haven't read the question fully enough: from the *protocol* standpoint it makes sense that the server is the first to communicate, as it's often the case (HTTP is kind-of an exception here) in order to tell the client to which server (software version, capabilities, ...) the client connected. From a *joke* perspective the client (i.e. the one "connecting") is certainly meant to start the knock-knock conversation.

Comment: Not necessarily (see my answer) - not if the server is supposed to be a *provider* of jokes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) says:

> When you successfully get a connection between the client and server, you will see the following text displayed on your screen:
>
> ```
> Server: Knock! Knock!
> ```

So it's actually the client that initiates the protocol (in network terms) but the server that initiates the joke (in conversational terms). Which I agree is rather confusing.

It might help if you think of it as a Joke Server - in order to get a joke, you have to ask for one! 
If it was the other way round, you'd have a server that just listens to jokes, which isn't as useful (unless you have absolutely no friends).